# All pages are giving 404 Error in Postman for Spring Boot application using Maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, http-status-code-404

https://github.com/SREEJA-PALLA/SpringBootCoursesAPI/tree/master

I'm getting a 404 error in postman this is my project.

{
"timestamp": "2021-05-18T17:46:24.979+00:00",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "",
"path": "/topics"
}

I checked the dependencies and also tried many ways but nothing seemed to work.
Can someone please help?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Adding traces will help to find the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have annotated your main application class with

```
@ComponentScan({"com.delivery.request"})
```

But this package does not exist in your codebase. So Spring does not find the Controller that you want it to find. This is in the package `com.example.courseData.topic`.

Comment: I made that change and now I have this error coming, and my applications.properties file is empty but I don't know what to add in there to configure my database:
Description:
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
Action: Consider the following:
 If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
 If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).